# How do I iterate across all sessions in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Our application has companies and uses in each company.  Each company has X number of licenses.  We are using a typed session class, and that class contains the id of the company along with other user information.  I need to add to our authentication process, a check to see if the current login will exceed a company's licenses.  I believe that the way to do this is to get a count of all company Ids across all sessions that match the companyId of the user currently trying to log in, and compare that count to the number of available licenses in our company table.  Is this a valid approach?  If so, please let me know how to query across all sessions, as I haven't figured it out and I'm still somewhat new to ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1):

### Using ICacheClientExtended API's

The `ICacheClientExtended` interface now supports a `GetKeysByPattern` API that lets you scan for matching keys on Cache Clients that implement the interface. Currently this is implemented by:

- MemoryCacheClient
- OrmLiteCacheClient
- Redis
- AWS DynamoDbCacheClient

This API now enables the new `GetAllKeys()` and `GetKeysStartingWith()` extension methods now available on `ICacheClient` to scan all cache keys.

```
var prefix = IdUtils.CreateUrn<IAuthSession>(""); //= urn:iauthsession:
var sessionKeys = Cache.GetKeysStartingWith(sessionPattern).ToList();
var userSessions = Cache.GetValues<AuthUserSession>(sessionKeys);
var existingSessions = userSessions.Values.Where(x => x != null).ToList();
```

Where `existingSessions` will contain list of active User Sessions.

Performance will be determined by how many active sessions you have which could be high depending on popularity of your site. Instead of searching all keys you may want to keep a set of session ids per company that you would look through instead by adding them to a collection in a [Session or Auth Event](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#session-events).

This new API is available from **v4.0.45+** of ServiceStack that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

The latest [DynamoDbCacheClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Aws/DynamoDb/DynamoDbCacheClient.cs) is now in the new **ServiceStack.Aws** NuGet package on MyGet which references the latest **v3.*** packages from the AWS SDK.

---

### Searching the underlying [Caching Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching)

Another option is access them directly from your `ICacheClient` [Caching provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) if it supports full scans, e.g. if you're using `OrmLiteCacheClient` to store sessions in an RDBMS you can access all Cache Entries with:

```
var sessionEntries = Db.Select<CacheEntry>(q => 
    q.Where(x => x.Id.StartsWith("urn:iauthsession:")));
var userSessions = sessionEntries.Map(x => 
    Db.Deserialize<AuthUserSession>(x.Data));
```

If you're using Redis for Caching you can get it with:

```
var sessionKeys = Redis.SearchKeys("urn:iauthsession:*");
var sessions = Redis.GetValues<AuthUserSession>(sessionKeys);
```

Another option would be to maintain a list of all Session Ids for each Company as each user logs in by registering a custom [Session or Auth Event](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#session-events) which you could maintain in a Redis SET or RDBMS table. In the same registration hook you can verify how many active Sessions they have by using `ICacheClient.GetAll` API and passing in the session keys for that company, something like:

```
var sessions = Cache.GetAll<AuthUserSession>(companySessionKeys);
var activeSessions = sessions.Values.Where(x => x != null).ToList();
```

Comment: I appreciate the input. We are moving to AWS DynamoDb, but I have little experience with it.  I was able to implement DynamoDb as my cache client, but am not certain how to access it in the way you described above.  We are using a PostgreSQL database for everything else, so Db = our PostgreSql connection.

Comment: @TortillaCurtain FYI I've updated the answer to include the new `ICacheClientExtended` API's that enables scanning of keys on supported Caching Providers. This is also supported by the new DynamoDbCacheClient in the ServiceStack.Aws NuGet package that's [now on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: This gives me a lot to work with, one of which will be convincing my team to use a pre-release...  One thing:  in your updated answer you stated "The latest DynamoDbCacheClient is now in the new ServiceStack.Aws NuGet which references the latest v3.* packages from the AWS SDK," but did you mean MyGet instead of NuGet in this sentence?

Comment: @TortillaCurtain yeah I meant NuGet package on MyGet, updated answer.

Comment: I switched our cache client from memory to OrmLite, and implemented the  solution above "Searching the underlying Caching Provider."  The sessionEntries come back as expected, but the userSessions do not.  I think it's because the values in the JSON in the Data field have property names in camel case, like "companyId":1, and the mapping to our strongly typed session is not working, because the userSessions come back with CompanyId with a value of zero.  I tried to deserialize just one value, and it behaves the same way.  Is my issue related to the case?  If so, what should I do?

Comment: Also, we have `JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;` set

Comment: your code above to get `userSessions` didn't work for me as I mentioned above.  I always got back a list of empty `MyCustomAuthSession` objects.  Instead I used `var userSessions = sessionEntries.Map(x => JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<MyCustomAuthSession>(x.Data));` and I got exactly what I expected.

Comment: I have this working using the "old" way, prior to the new version.  One thing that has come up however, is getting sessions that are still in the database, but left there from a user who selected "remember me" at login.  So they may or may not be actively using the application, but the method to count the licenses in use will count one of these sessions as a license.  What do you recommend to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

A little speed check:

I am using InMemoryAuthRepository, and if I have 1000 sessions in cache, and I fetch them, it takes 21 ms. The fetching starts at 4 ms (for 1 session) and goes up to 21 ms for a 1000.

```js
sw.Restart();
IDictionary<string, IAuthSession> sessionList = cacheClient?.GetAll<IAuthSession>(cacheClient?.GetAllKeys());
sw.Stop();
totalMs += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
counter2speed.Add(counter, totalMs);
```